Bad UART data between MCU and Raspberry Pi
I'm doing some UART stuff between a Raspberry Pi 4B and a custom PCB with an STM32 (LPUART). I am transmitting
hello world\n

constantly, but what's being received is a bit different. It is receiving the correct amount of bytes and it gets some letters correct, but the others are not received properly.
Here's what the receiving end looks like

What could the problem be? Is it a mismatch in UART settings? It's not in the amount of data bits (8), stop bits (1) or parity (no parity). Could it be poor hardware connection? Do you recognize the pattern?
Thanks
EDIT:
Stopped using the raspberry pi because I ran into some problems with it. Now I use an RS232 to USB 2.0 converter and read the serial data with RealTerm on COM3. The first problem was the cryptic documentation in the LPUART1 section of the reference manual. I was directly writing the desired baud rate in to BRR but turned out I needed to write a divider there. Now the bps seems OK.
Still not working. When the STM32 outputs 'A' between 1 second intervals, RealTerm just outputs 0x00 in hex view and  % in Ascii but after a while it starts outputting _ in Ascii view.  The BREAK and Error status flags are flashing red. It says 'UART receiver framing error'. Looking at the signal on the oscilloscope, the start and stop bits seem totally fine to me, but apparently they're not. They share a common ground.

I've been trying to get basic UART working for 3 weeks. WTF

Very hard to read any detail in your image. Can you give it another try. And presumably you are transmitting from the pi to the device? What IDE are you using on the STM32?

It would be more helpful to see the hexadecimal dump of received data instead. It does seem that some 0 bits are turned into 1 bits; in particular, space (0x20) gets sometimes turned into backtick (0x60). Presumably the symbols get their high bit turned on. But the 0xA (0xD?) never gets mangled?!
Anyway, the best thing to do would be get an oscilloscope hooked onto that uart line. You don't have one nearby by any chance?

Please [edit] your question to contain the output you get as text, rather than a (very blurry) image. Do your boards share a common ground (0V)?

"I am transmitting ..." - Have you to turned into a computer? Is the "MCU" or the "Raspberry Pi" the transmitter? What method is used to perform this "transmitting*"? What method is used to perform the receiving?

Are devices' grounds connected? Can you view the received data as raw binary? Are you sure about parity bit? By default STM UART uses no parity.

@AndreyTurkin To me the oscilloscope reading seems fine, except the bit timing is a little bit off.. what do you think?

Doesn't look right to me. What's the supposed UART speed here? At the standard 115200 bps we should expect 1e6/115200=8.7 us per bit. You are measuring twice that (rather, half). If your PC side expect 115200 then it definitely won't get any good data.

@AndreyTurkin The PC side expects a baud rate of 230400, so the bits are supposed to be half as long as with 115200.

Ah, ok. Then it does look right, with less than 2% speed deviation which should be totally fine. And logical 1 is well above 5v input tolerance. Assuming you are using UART-USB converter and not RS232-USB like stated, assuming it can handle this baud rate, and if you took these readings while hooked to the converter (so we know this is what it saw), it should work.

@AndreyTurkin It is a RS232-USB converter. Correct me if I'm wrong, but aren't RS232 and UART pretty much the same thing? Atleast when looking at the wikipedia page for RS232, the protocol looks identical to UART.

Technically these are apples and oranges, but colloquially we're talking about different physical representation of the same protocol. RS232 defines 0/1 voltages swinging from at least -3v to +3v with regard to the ground; that is achieved by using a driver chip like MAX232; RS232-USB converters are intended for use with RS232 ports like external COM ports on PC, usually via DB9 connectors. On the other hand, UART(TTL)-USB converters do not have the driver chip; they operate on 3v/5v TTL levels and intended for direct connection to UART pins of various chips (hence UART in their name).

@AndreyTurkin So I need to buy a TTL-USB converter?

I guess. If what you have is a rs232 converter - that won't work (it could easily damage your mcu instead). Raspberry pi could do the job but you say there are some issues with it as well. So, yeah. It's quite cheap, and also almost a must have item for anyone who tinkers with MCUs.

Not a programming question. You simply had wrong converter. Delete this question as it has no value for the community

I bought a USB-TTL converter and used it instead of a USB-RS232 converter and it works now.
